# Node.JS object prototype may only be an Object or null with Redis

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis

I've been trying to setup redis for my Node.JS API
and I've been getting this error:

```
util.js:634
  ctor.prototype = Object.create(superCtor.prototype, {
                          ^
TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined
    at Function.create (native)
    at Object.exports.inherits (util.js:634:27)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/<user>/<project>/node_modules/redis/lib/parser/javascript.js:31:6)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/<user>/<project>/node_modules/redis/index.js:33:14)
```

Here's my code:

```
console.log('Redis: ' + config.redis.host);
console.log('Redis: ' + config.redis.port);
console.log('Redis: ' + config.redis.pass);

redis       = require('redis');
redisClient = redis.createClient(
    config.redis.port, 
    config.redis.host, 
    {
        auth_pass: config.redis.pass
    }
);
```

config is simply a require('config') file with a config object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the issue. I had a global variable called `Error` which conflicted with redis, and also some other dependencies.

I fixed it by simply re-naming `Error` to `Errors`.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense -- and this is part of why global variables should be avoided whenever possible. FYI, `Error` is [a standard JavaScript thing](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.11).

Comment: Yes, I know that, which is why I changed it.

Comment: What exactly did you rename?

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that `superCtor.prototype` is `undefined`. The only valid first argument to `Object.create` is either `null` or a non-`null` object reference; you can't use primitives (including `undefined`).

We can't say *why* `superCtor.prototype` is undefined from the code you've quoted, but that's the problem with the `Object.create` call.