# NodeJS TypeError after restarting the node server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm, ejs

I'm building a web app with Node.js, Express framework, and EJS templates.

Here's my server:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.get('/', (req,res) => {
  res.render('home', {
    headline : 'We are always on a mission for Clearn Benglauru'
  });
});

app.use(express.static(__dirname, '/public'));
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`The app is running on port : ${PORT}`);
});
```

After starting the server, I got this error:

```
TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: /public
    at Function.create (<anonymous>)
    at Function.serveStatic [as static] (<DIRECTORY>\node_modules\serve-static\index.js:48:21)
    at Object.<anonymous> (<DIRECTORY>\test:12:23)
```

Maybe related to [Node.JS object prototype may only be an Object or null with Redis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30426420/node-js-object-prototype-may-only-be-an-object-or-null-with-redis)

Comment: I expected that  I will get downvotes. Guys, please give solutions instead of voting for the unintentional mistake. Really I need your help.

Comment: what is the problem , explain more..we cant guess your problem..

Comment: Is that is okay if I give my repository link? Please help me.

Comment: app.use(express.static(__dirname, '/public'));
This was the line giving trouble to me. When we are serving static files without path then we have to concat it. We should not use ','.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the module `path` to serve your public folder.

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/', (req,res) => {
    res.status(200).send('Ok!');
});

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`The app is running on port : ${PORT}`);
});
```

I didn't have EJS or an EJS view file, so I replaced the `res.render` line with a `res.status().send()` for the example. Tested and works.

Comment: app.use(express.static(__dirname, '/public'));
This was the line giving trouble to me. When we are serving static files without path then we have to concat it. We should not use ','.